# Facebook login with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am implementing Facebook login on my website. I am creating an asp.net user as well with the Facebook users details. This way I can control login in people to my site using .NET membership regardless of whether they are a Facebook user or not.

The problem I am facing now is security. When a user logs in with Facebook I am calling a webservice with their facebook details, if the user exists on the system (by their facebook userid) then I log them in. However as it stands anyone could call the webservice with someone elses facebook id and it would log them in (if that user existed on the system). Is there something that I can use to link the facebook user with my asp.net user that is only accessible to that user, such as an access token. It also needs to be something which does not change? Does facebook send back such a thing in the response object?

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Facebook login button or some 'other' mechanism? What 'webservice' are you calling for facebook details?

Comment: If you use Facebook login button you can check whether the user logged in successfully that time. Do you do that?

Comment: I am using the facebook Javascript API. I call FB.login and then use the response object to call my own webservice.

Comment: It seems to mme that problem is what your 'webservice' accepts as valid input from Facebook login. You are worried that some user#1 may login to your web and user#2 may read the data sent to your 'webservice' (which can be simple) and then user#2 may call directly your webservice - not using your Asp.Net web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can get that profile data from Facebook. Using that requestAccessToken Url you can get that access token.

requestAccessTokenurl="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0} redirect_uri={1};client_secret={2};code={3}"

Also we can get the Profile Data using this access token
requestProfileUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/me"

please see this link- http://easyoauth.codeplex.com/

you can download the source code also :)

We have implemented for Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google using this framework. It is very straight forward. I can help you how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: please go through this link http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/

Comment: So is an access token unique and does it never change? I need something that is only accessible by the facebook user logging in. Thanks

Comment: please see the below link. It may give you some idea how to proceed with your requirement. http://bhaidar.net/post/2011/04/04/OpenID-Single-Sign-On-ASPNET-Web-Forms.aspx

Comment: I really like the look of easyauth. Do you by any chance know of how to implement the verification. The examples do not show that part. Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly you need? What does this mean " how to implement the verification/" ? Please tell me so that I can help you.